# PHP / MySQL: How to query data from 2 tables linked with link table

Tags: php, mysql

I created 3 MySQL tables, of which the last one's purpose is to make n:m relationships between the first two tables possible:

```
EVENT
event_id
event_name

TAG
tag_id
tag_name

EVENT2TAG
event_id
tag_id
```

Now I struggle to create a MySQL query with PHP, that produces list of all events and all their respective tags, e.g. like this:

```
<div>
  <h1>My first event</h1>
  #show
  #expo
  #freefood
</div>
        
<div>
  <h1>Another, even better Event</h1>
  #show
  #tv
  #conference
  #freedrinks
</div>
        
<div>
  <h1>Lame event</h1>
  #expo
  #boring
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Show us the code you've tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want joins?

```
select e.event_name, t.tag_name
from event e
inner join event2tag et on et.event_id = t.e.event_id
inner join tag t on t.tag_id = et.tag_id
order by e.event_id, t.tag_id
```

This gives you one row per event/tag tuple, with their associated names. You can iterate through the results in your application to display the results.

You might also be interested in generating a single row per event, with all the tags aggregated in a comma-separated string:

```
select e.event_name, group_concat(t.tag_name order by t.tag_id) all_tags
from event e
inner join event2tag et on et.event_id = t.e.event_id
inner join tag t on t.tag_id = et.tag_id
group by e.event_id, e.event_name
```